# Handling mailto links with mu4e

Tags: email, mu4e

How do I get mu4e to handle `xdg-open mailto:foo@bar`?
I couldn't even find a function taking an address as an argument that will open a composition buffer.

Comment: [According to the author](https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1045) `mu4e` doesn't have an specific functions for handling mailto: URLs. The EmacsWiki has a page on writing [a mailto handler](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MailtoHandler) to get the mailto from your command-line to your composition buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has appropriate `.desktop`-files in its source code, dedicated for opening `mailto` URLs: One for [Emacsclient](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/emacsclient-mail.desktop), another for [Emacs](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/emacs-mail.desktop). Make sure you *installed* and *configured* them correctly.

For installation, ensure that you have a `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable with colon-separated directories, so that one of those directories contains a subdirectory that contains one of the above mentioned `.desktop` files.

For configuration, ensure that there is an environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` so that there is a file at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list` which contains something like this:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/mailto=emacsclient-mail.desktop
```

Also make sure you set these two variables in Emacs. The second variable will tell Emacs' `message.el` to use Mu4e for composing e-mails, as defined in the first variable.

```
(setq
  mail-user-agent #'mu4e-user-agent
  message-mail-user-agent t)
```